# Evaluating Android app startup time with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

What are the things to consider when optimizing App Startup Time? Or how it should be done? Does that need a few run tests then it will be evaluated?

I am new to android app development and I apologize for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio >3.2 now has an option in configuration/profiling to start recording from application start and then automatically opens the profile with all needed information.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/android-studio-32.html

Will give you nearly everything you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Just "Disabling filters, and finding the Displayed value in logcat."

Checkout here https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#dx

Answer (score -1):

1) "Evaluating"

you can use Android profiler to monitor Memory, CPU and Network Usage of the application.
just run your application, open profiler and that's it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2BDm.png)

2) "Optimizing"

In terms of Size: you can use Lint marks to remove unused resources. prefer to use Vector resources

In terms of performance: Lint marks to remove unused variables, imports, converting instance variables to local if it can be converted etc. Load Bitmaps if you have any with Glide (image load library).